# HTML structure for showing page title as a selected submenu item

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

On a category archive, I want to use the following layout:

```
CATEGORY NAME

[All] - Subcategory 1 - Subcategory 2 - Subcategory 3

List of all posts from 'CATEGORY NAME'
```

with *All* highlighted.

When somebody clicks on a subcategory, that category highlights and they see posts from that subcategory:

```
CATEGORY NAME

All - [Subcategory 1] - Subcategory 2 - Subcategory 3

List of all posts from 'Subcategory 1'
```

It is perfectly clear to users what this means, and that the latter means you are on that subcategory's page.

What is the best way to make this clear to search engines?

As per standard practice, the 'page title' should be an `h1` tag. For the first case, this is clearly the category name. However, in the latter case it should be the subcategory. Adding an `h1` inside a navigation list doesn't really make any sense; but keeping the `h1` tag on the top level category name doesn't really give the right impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have markup like this:

```html
<h1>CATEGORY NAME</h1>
<nav><!-- links to "All" and subcategories --></nav>
<div><!-- List of all posts --></div>
```

You are right that it’s not appropriate to change/add headings inside of the `nav`, as this would only affect the outline of the `nav` element itself, and not the outline of the parent.

One solution might be to change the `h1` accordingly (e.g., "CATEGORY NAME: Subtitle 1"). However, this doesn’t really make sense as long as the `nav` is a subsection.

Another solution (and I think this one is more appropriate): add a `h2` that reflects the chosen page:

```
<h1>CATEGORY NAME</h1>
<nav><!-- links to "All" and subcategories --></nav>
<section>
  <h2>Subcategory 1</h2>
  <div><!-- List of all posts from 'Subcategory 1' --></div>
</section>
```

If *All* is chosen, you could of course use a `h2` with something like "All posts", but that might not be very elegant; instead, you could consider omitting the `section` in that case and use the markup from the first snippet above.

Comment: The extra heading is a possibility, but I guess the main issue is that it's repeating the same information as highlighting the selected menu item does. To human visitors, the extra heading is superfluous and seems a little strange repeating it based on the design we're using for the selected menu item.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, I can see that this solution is not appropriate for some designs. -- In such cases, I typically visually hide (with CSS) the heading element. That way visitors able to see your design don’t get the repeated information, but screen reader users do (especially useful for those users that skip the `nav`).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I might have to do that. Having an important heading hidden with CSS also doesn't feel like a great solution from an SEO perspective though. Will leave this open a while longer in case anyone can come up with anything better.